# anchor to a pdf file in internet explorer

Tags: html, pdf, web, internet-explorer-9, anchor

I have an anchor with the attribute **href** pointing to a pdf file, like **127.0.0.1/MyApp/myfile.pdf**, but the anchor simply doesn't work on Internet Explorer 9. It's ok in FF and Chrome. I didn't get any error in IE's javascript console, and there isn't any traffic at all when I hit the link.

```
<a href="/MyApp/foo/bar.pdf"><label>Click to see the PDF file</label></a>
```

There's no css associate that is relevant...

Comment: There is not enough relevant code here for us to help you.  Please provide all the HTML and CSS to demonstrate the problem, but without anything irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved! The issue was that I was adding a **label**, inside the **link**, thus IE couldn't render the link properly. Instead, I put it on a **span** tag, and the link is working.

Thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As KatieK pointed out, you haven't provided enough information to work with here. However, I had faced something similar a while back, this helped me solve the issue:

1. Open Reader
2. Edit > Preferences.
3. Internet > Display PDF in Browser

But I am not sure if it's a similar issue with yours too.

Comment: no.. it didn't help me. the problem is that the link simply doesn't work... when the user clicks the link, it has the same effect hat if the user is doing nothing. got it? 
what kind of code can I put here? I already editted the question and provided the html code with the anchor a.